# Run command inside awk and store result inplace

Tags: awk

I have a script that I need to run on every value. It basically return a number by taking an argument, like below

```
>>./myscript 4832
>>1100
```

`my.csv` contains the following:

```
123,4832
456,4833
789,4834
```

My command

```
cat my.csv | awk -F',' '{$3=system("../myscript $2");print $1,$2,$3'}
```

`myscript` is unable to understand that I'm passing the second input field `$2` as argument. I need the output from the script to be added to the output as my 3rd column.

The expected output is

```
123,4832,1100
456,4833,17
789,4834,42
```

where the third field is the output from `myscript` with the second field as the argument.

Comment: I't not clear what you mean by `$2`.  The first command-line argument is `$1` but the Awk variable `$1` is distinct from the shell variable `$1` and means something quite different.  Could you please clarify what exactly you expect to happen here?

Comment: Also note the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: I want my 2nd field value in the my.csv file to go as an argument to my script and save the result from script as 3rd field in my.csv

Comment: Updated question with a clarification; please review.

Answer (score 3):

If you are attempting to add a third field with the output from `myscript $2` where `$2` is the value of the second field, try

```
awk -F , '{ printf ("%s,%s,", $1, $2); system("../myscript " $2) }' my.csv
```

where we exploit the convenient fact that the output from `myscript` will complete the output without a newline with the calculated value and a newline.

This isn't really a good use of Awk; you might as well do

```
while IFS=, read -r first second; do
    printf "%s,%s," "$first" "$second"
    ../mycript "$second"
done <my.csv
```

I'm assuming you require comma-separated output; changing this to space-separated is obviously a trivial modification.

Comment: it return me ,outputbyscript I tried running `while IFS=, read -r first second; do     printf "%s,%s," "$first" "$second";  done <my.csv` this prints single , only

Comment: Yeah, you left out the call to `myscript` which supplies the third field *and the newline,* like I tried to explain.  If you want a newline from `printf`, that's `printf "%s,%s,\n" "$first" "$second"` but ... I really can't guess where you want to go with this.

Comment: No, I was just trying to check the command without calling script at all, it should have printed 1st 2 columns

Comment: That's what it does.  Without the newline.

Answer (score 1):

We can use in gnu-awk [Two-Way Communications with Another Process](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO)

```
awk -F',' '{"../myscript "$2 |& getline v; print $1,$2,v}' my.csv
```

you get,

```
123 4832 1100
456 4833 17
789 4834 42
```

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }{"../myscript "$2 |& getline v; print $1,$2,v}' my.csv
```

you get,

```
123,4832,1100
456,4833,17
789,4834,42
```

Comment: This gives me only results from my script. <space>value by script (my script output is given in newline, i wonder if that is a problem)

Comment: It does not print $1,$2 but v (prefixed by space)

Comment: @pythonRcpp I fixed my post

Comment: still the same result

Comment: If you want comma-separated output, you need `BEGIN { OFS=FS }` before the rest of the script.  It's not clear from your question that you have this additional requirement.

Comment: You should mention that this is a gawk-specific extension, it will not work in other awks.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you want is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
{
    cmd = "./myscript \047" $2 "\047"
    val = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "NaN" )
    close(cmd)
    print $0, val
}
' file
```

Tweak the getline part to do different error handling if you like and make sure you read and fully understand http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline before using getline.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `$2` separately in the string concatenation, that is

```
awk -F',' '{ system("echo \"echo " $1 "$(../myexecutable " $2 ") " $3 "\" | bash"); }' my.csv
```

Comment: It gives me `127100 4832155200921276976
: No such file or directoryter4832155200921276984` 
Myscript return answer in newline(should that be a problem?). 127100 and 4...6 are my 2 column values in my.csv

Comment: The basic reason is that your question fails to specify what you actually want.  But `system("echo")` is probably not a good answer to any question.

Comment: The basic advice to put `$2` outside the double quotes is spot on, though,

Comment: @pythonRcpp would you mind running the edited script and see what it does.

Comment: Now it gives me firstcolumn<nospace>valuefromscript (looks very close to the expected solution

Comment: Should work, though. I edited 'bash ../myscript' which is the only thing I could image to cause trouble.

Comment: `awk -F',' '{ system("echo " $1 ",$(../myscript  " $2 ") " $3); }' my.csv`  gives me field1,outputFromScript how do i include $2 btw my script is a cpp binary !

Comment: Note, that there is no ',' between " and $(. I do not know why it does not work for you. You may try running 'awk' from 'bash'.

Comment: `$(...)` is a bash-ism. system() calls /bin/sh which may not be bash and that is independent of whichever shell you were running when you invoked awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. I adapted the line to explicitly call 'bash'.

Comment: @EdMorton `$(...)` is not a Bashism, it has been in POSIX for ages (though might still be a problem on stalwart pre-POSIX systems like legacy Solaris etc).

Answer (score 0):

from GNU awk online documentation:

*system: Execute the operating system command command and then return to the awk program. Return command’s exit status (see further on).*

you need to use getline [getline piped documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe)